# How to set animation to move an object by a distance and not from one place to another

Tags: animation, objects, transforms

Is it possible to make blender (on timeline) move an object by X distance instead of making him move it from A to B. This way using it would be more flexible and allow for same movement of objects with different origin.

Comment: no but you can parent it to an empty: if you move this empty it will shift the animation. Also you can use the Delta Transforms, or create a collection instance, and same thing, it will shift the animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, a keyframe is relative to the world coordinate, but there are ways to shift the action:

- You can parent your object to an empty: if you move this empty it will shift the animation
- You can use the *Delta Transforms*: In the *Object panel > Transform*, change the *Location* values
- You can put your object into a collection, create a collection instance (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Collection Instance*) and move it wherever you want

Comment: I don't think any of these works? Just tried careful three hours maybe all three. Failures.

Comment: hello, it should work but maybe ask a new question with all the details?